# PayPal missing Webhook event

Tags: paypal, paypal-webhooks

Hi all and especially PayPal developer support,

I am a developer from a medium-sized company. We have integrated with PayPal for payout and for most of our users it's working fine. But there are about 50 users that initiated the payout, in which case we sent the requests to PayPal and finally paid them out (I checked them in PayPal ledger). But we never got any event back from Paypal (neither batch event or item event). I am wondering what is the reason for that and what is PayPal's recommendation for those transactions.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if the webhook url are responding properly?